# Randomly Display One Image From a 10-Image For Loop

Tags: loop, admin, metabox, options

I have a Wordpress function that loops thru 10 input fields & saves the data from those input fields. The data entered is either an absolute or relative link to an image. The loop looks like this.

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i < 11; $i++) { ?>

    <input type="text" name="<?php echo 'fresh_banner'.$i ?>" value="<?php echo $settings['fresh_banner'.$i]; ?>" />

<?php } ?>
```

The saving looks like this:

```
<?php

function freshSaveThemeSettings() {

    $settings = get_option( "freshThemeSettings" );

        for ($i = 1; $i < 11; $i++) {

            $settings['fresh_banner'.$i] = $_POST['fresh_banner'.$i];

        }

    $updated = update_option( "freshThemeSettings", $settings );

}

?>
```

To output one of the images, it goes something like this:

```
<?php 

    $settings = get_option( "freshThemeSettings" ); 

    echo $settings['fresh_banner1']; 

?>
```

What I'm trying to do is randomly display one of the images at a time. Each time the page is refreshed, a new image would be displayed. What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a basic PHP question than a WordPress one!

```
$settings = get_option( "freshThemeSettings" ); 
$random = rand( 1, 11 );

if ( isset( $settings[ "fresh_banner$random" ] ) )
    echo $settings[ "fresh_banner$random" ];
```

Comment: Yeah I feel ya. But any mention of Wordpress over at Stackoverflow is just askin for it. Thanks a ton for the help, this should work just fine!